# Does exist a universal tool to describe different APIs (REST, WebSocket, gRPC, custom framework)?

Tags: api, websocket, swagger, documentation, grpc

My project uses different protocols to communicate with other services:

- REST API
- WebSocket (STOMP)
- gRPC
- own framework build over gRPC.

I need a tool, or a bunch of tools, which allow me to generate documentation for the APIs. In the best scenario, it's a maven plugin that generates a report with all APIs.

We use Swagger to describe the REST API. It has poor export options and needs a lot of annotations in the code, but describes the API well and offer the test machine.
Alternatively, Spring RestDocs (AsciiDoctor) could be used for the REST API describing. It offers a better format for reporting, but we prefer Swagger.

That's all I found for the REST API. But I didn't find anything for describing WebSocket API, gRPC and the custom framework.

I will be very grateful for any help and ideas to solve the problem.